# What is an idiomatic French equivalent of the English expression "fast forward ten years"?

Tags: expressions, indications-de-temps

> To think he was an absolute novice at 'everything computer'! **Fast forward ten years**, and here he is, running an IT business.

I wonder if there is a more appropriate alternative to the rather straightforward "10 ans plus tard"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If “*Dix ans plus tard*” feels a little too austere and perhaps lifeless for you, here are a few other possibilities that you may find a bit more dynamic:

> Sautons dix ans en avant et le voici aux rênes d’une entreprise informatique.
>
> Faisons un bond de dix ans et ...

Or maybe simply reverse the first two parts to avoid a comma and speed up the whole thing:

> Le voici dix ans plus tard aux commandes d’une entreprise informatique.

Comment: Any expression like: _on déroule le film dix ans plus loin_? (I know that one doesn't work, but maybe we have one related to tapes, or movies, or cassettes.

Comment: _Sautons_ or _Faisons un bond_ are both quite dynamic, but indeed related rather to human physical capacities rather than to the specific vocabulary of a music/video playing device. Here in Quebec, most of these devices came from the English country right beside and didn’t have any French labels on them. So we used mostly _avancer_ & _reculer_ without any extra bit of info concerning the speed of the process. As far as I know, it is still the current way of referring to _fast forward_ and _rewind_ (the latter of which also lacks any speed indicator). So short answer: I don’t know.

Comment: Curieusement, j'ai trouvé ceci dans CNRTL: [En parlant de la suite des jours, de la vie, p. allus. au fil des Parques dans la myth gr.] La bobine de tes jours (Amiel, Journal intime,1866, p. 474).

Comment: Vous semblez plein de ressources! J’ai déjà rencontré _rembobiner_ pour faire allusion à un retour dans le passé (“_Rembobinons dix ans et nous retrouvons ce chef d’entreprise incapable de démarrer un ordinateur_”). Un débobinage vers le futur me semble plus exotique, et je n’ai jamais rencontré cette forme. Belle trouvaille néanmoins.

Comment: C'est une coïncidence - je cherchais une expression en rapport avec les films, puis je me suis souvenu de _bobine_, puis j'ai regardé dans CNRTL à _bobine_, qui ne m'a pas donné l'expression toute faite que j'espérais, mais qui mentionnait cette toute petite référence au fil des Parques! Petite trouvaille au hasard :-)

Comment: Ce matin, je me suis soudainement rappelé que le verbe _débobiner_ existe au figuré en français, et  bien que vraisemblablement plus lié à la bobine de fil qu’à la bobine de film, l’image pourrait être facilement transférée de l’une vers l’autre. Seulement, c’est le désorde incontrôlable plus que la vitesse d’accès au matériel embobiné (fil ou pellicule) qui est mis de l’avant, et être _débobiné_, c’est être désemparé, _débobiner_ un adversaire, c’est le mettre dans une position difficile à tenir. C’est un peu à l’écart du sujet, mais votre intéressante recherche m’inspirais.

Comment: Eh oui :-) Pour ce qui est d'utiliser _bobine_ dans ce genre de contexte, je ne serais pas surpris d'entendre (et je comprendrais immédiatement): _on rembobine la pellicule dix ans en arrière, et l'on retrouve notre héro ... _ dans un film, par exemple.

Answer (score 5):

*Dix ans plus tard* is fine. You just need to write *dix* in letters, not 10.

Comment: One can extend it to "Et nous voilà dix ans plus tard". BTW you have a typo: *and* instead of *ans*.

Comment: @Fatalize Thanks for the typo. Yes variations are possible although I refrained to use "et" because there is already one starting the next clause.  It can be used but then, the full sentence translation should be considered.